# jquery trigger works after clicking on li that it supposed to trigger automatically the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ten li lists.

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I have my jquery trigger set like this and wrap around in a clickable button.

```
  $("#autoSelectLi").live("click", function(event)
  {
        $("paginationList li:eq(6)").trigger("click");
  });
```

The first time I tried to click on #autoSelectLi, nothing works. But if I manually click on li 7 and then click #autoSelectLi click on any other li (for example, li 1), then the auto jquery trigger works by automatically clicking on li 7.

Here's the code that gets executed after using jquery trigger method.

```
  $("paginationList li").live("mouseenter", "mouseout", function(event)
  {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      if(event.type == "mouseenter")
      {
         $(this).on("click", function(evt)
         {
              evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
              // rest of code.......
         });
      }
```

Comment: why are you using live?.. What version of jQuery are you using? Live is deprecated after version 1.7  http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Yes..live is deprecated. Also, pls post your HTML too.

Comment: i prefer to use `on()` other side your selector is not selecting correct you have currently `$("paginationList li:eq(6)").trigger("click");` it must be a class `.paginationList ` or id `#paginationList`

Comment: Why add `click` event at each `mouseenter` ? Should event passed be `mouseenter mouseout` , without `,` ?

Comment: do not bind any event inside any other event....this could lead to a hotch-potch behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed the click handlers for your li elements so that they will only be initialised when you put the mouse over them (and every time you put the mouse over them so you could end up with many many handlers for each). Remove the 'mouseenter' handlers and just put the click handlers directly into $(document).ready